# Is Objective-C an Interpreted or Compiled language?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know that Objective-C an Interpreted or Compiled language, i have read so many blogs and all but not getting any proper answer for that.

Thanks in Advance if any one want to throw a light on this Question.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/94196/is-objective-c-an-interpreted-or-compiled-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not accurate to say that a language is interpreted or compiled because interpretation and compilation are both properties of the implementation of that particular language, and not a property of the language itself. So, in theory, any language can be compiled or interpreted – it just depends on what the particular implementation that you are using does.

[Reference link](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/whats-the-difference-between-a-compiled-and-an-interpreted-language/)